# How to get a variable value by variable name

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

when executing inside a function there is a variable named id

```
int id = 0;
```

inside the function I'm loading a instance of a class which is containing the varable name in a string

```
obj a { varableName = "id" }
```

I want to access the variable from the string name and get the value from it, how is this possible.

Comment: I need to see a little more of your code to understand what you're trying to do. Can you share your entire function, please?? Right now, it looks like a myA = new a(); a.variableName=id;

Comment: You must use Reflection.

Comment: to execute a web-service function with string format, ex: string.format("customer/getcustomerbyid/{id}", 46)

Comment: already tried this.GetType().GetField("id").GetValue(this); not working, object reference null error is coming

Comment: Ok now we REALLY need to see your code.

Comment: Where is `id` defined? Show your class the property belongs to.

Comment: Not GetField, try GetProperty, but therefore it has to be a property, not a variable

Comment: Reflection almost never is the way to go, unless you're dealing with serialization. Store the values in a dictionary instead.

Answer (score 1):

You can get it by reflection:

```
variableName = this.GetType().GetProperty("id").GetValue(this, null);
```

Comment: Then it should be this.GetType().GetProperty(variableName).GetValue(this, null);

Comment: This assumes it's a property, which the code from the OP is not.